# Formatting Gridview display in ASPX page

Tags: asp.net, gridview, css, formatting

[image]Scenario : I have an ASPX page with Gridview. Every row has one column heading and it's value. At the end of record there is a generic line.

My issue is with formatting and CSS.

I would like the output to be as below (I have tried to format but upon posting it is loosing)

---

### |  Customer Name   | Microsoft  |

### |  Customer City   |  Seattle   |

### |                               |

### |  Customer Name   | DowJones   |

### |  Customer City   |     NYC    |

Above the customer name is centered to that cell. Similarly it's value also (Microsoft). Also CustomerName is colored with darkblack and "Microsoft" with just black.

The '-----' and "|" are actually table borders/seperators. It is typical table with borders and horizontal line and vertical line.

Please suggest. Below is my code.

```
        <div style="width:400px; font-family:Arial; font-size:small">
      <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        Width="100%" GridLines= "Horizontal">
        <Columns>
          <asp:TemplateField>
          <ItemTemplate> 


            <div style="color:Blue;font-weight:bold">
            <br />
            <tr>
              <td><asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='Customer NAME' cssclass ="blackboldhdr" ></asp:Label></td>
              <td><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"DealerName") %>' cssclass ="blackboldtxt"></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='Customer City'></asp:Label></td>
              <td><asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"City") %>'></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>

            </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
          </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>    

            <style> 
    .blackboldtxt {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        color:black;
        font-weight: bold;

    }
    .blackboldhdr
    {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        /*color:#FFFFFF;*/
        background-color: #2A3C54;
        width: 152px; 
        text-align:center;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: I take it that your CSS is not doing what you want it to do? How is it appearing instead?  You might also want to try the old-fashioned Repeater control rather than trying to force the GridView to do multiple table rows.

Comment: Yes, the CSS is not doing what I expected to do. I tried with Repeater but no success. Is there a problem with Gridview to do formatting as per CSS?

Comment: Can you describe how the page actually appears at run time and how that differs from the way you want it to appear?

Comment: I have attached snapshot of what I am getting and what I am looking for. thanks

Comment: Your HTML is badly formatted is likely the problem. GridView spits out each column into a table cell, and you are trying to write out rows in there. I would use a Repeater, or wrap everything in a table tag inside that column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can use `<tr>` and `<td>` elements inside the grid's itemTemplate. Since the grid will already render `<tr>...</tr>` for each row and `<td> {Item template's content}  </td>`, the result would be invalid HTML code.

I think you should use a [Repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx) instead of the Grid, e.g. something like this:

```
<asp:Repeater>
  <HeaderTemplate><table class="..."></HeaderTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
      <td class="blackboldhdr">
        <asp:Label runat="server" Text='Customer NAME' cssclass="blackboldhdr"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <asp:Label runat="server"  cssclass ="blackboldtxt"
           Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"DealerName") %>' />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        ... same as above, but for customer address
    </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>
  <SeparatorTemplate><tr><td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td></tr>
  <FooterTemplate></table></FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: I used the above asp:Repeater and seems to be better than what I was getting with Gridview. Do I need to specify the width for repeater because page width has increased. Currently I have just <asp:Repeater>
  <HeaderTemplate><table style ="width:auto"></HeaderTemplate>      Also how to get the vertical and horizontal lines for each row. I showed this in my attachment in original post.

Comment: I would use CSS to set borders, colors, etc. E.g. define a class on the table, then use some CSS like `table.myClass td { border-bottom: solid 1px black; }`, and so on.